# Parameters of ligthgbm tweedie

Tags: regression, lightgbm, tweedie

I'm using the `tweedie` option for the `objective` parameter of the lightgbm package.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweedie_distribution), the tweedie distribution has a free parameter **p**, but I can't seem to find the way to give it a value.

Does anyone know how to do it? What is the value by default?

Answer (score 0):

from lightgbm [documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html)

it's known as tweedie_variance_power. it's used to control the variance of the tweedie distribution and must be set into this interval 1 <= p <= 2

set this closer to 2 to shift towards a Gamma distribution

set this closer to 1 to shift towards a Poisson distribution

default value = 1.5